# Different g++ and clang behaviour for SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am writing template that should check, if have type default constructor.

```
void _void_f(){}

template<typename T, typename ENABLE = void>
struct is_constructible_default {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_constructible_default<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype((T()), _void_f()),void>::value>::type> {
    static const bool value = true;
}
```

This works fine for classes with implemented constructor, generated constructor or without default constructor. However, when is default constructor private, the g++ compiler exit with error, that T() is private. But because of SFINAE, the error should just ignore that overload.
For clang, this implementation works fine. How is  std::is_default_constructible implemented for g++?

https://godbolt.org/g/qAZaJb

Which compiler is right here?

---

I probably found solution for g++. STL implementation use SFINAE for method instead of using enable_if.

```
struct is_default_constructible_impl
{
    template<typename T, typename = decltype(T())>
    static std::true_type test(int);

    template<typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template<typename T>
struct is_constructible_default : decltype(is_default_constructible_impl::test<T>(0))
{};
```

https://godbolt.org/g/DQ4yZp

Comment: For the record, this also happens with private vs not-existing members and typedefs.

Comment: No its not, for nonexisting or deleted constructor the implementation works even in g++: https://godbolt.org/g/DDLG2G

Comment: [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82478) is a related bug report

Comment: @PatrikValkovič I meant this difference is still there for other members - it's not only for constructors.

Comment: [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61806) is another report updated a few days ago. Looks like a GCC bug.